# Auto-generate jQuery script from HTML

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, code-generation, auto-generate

Is there any tool / library which would:

1. Take HTML markup as input
2. **Auto-generate a jQuery script** which, in return, if executed, would
3. Generate the original HTML?

Comment: Nothing personal, but... You're doing something wrong if you need such thing. It depends on how complex your HTML is. If there's something pretty simple, then `$('<div class="content">...</div>')` will do.

Comment: If it is a little more complex, `$.parseHTML(...)` should help you as well. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

Comment: @AndrewDunai, works perfectly in my case, thanks! You may also add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it (maybe just add a reference to the official doc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in comment, It depends on how complex your HTML is.

If there's something pretty simple, then

```
$('<div class="content">...</div>')
```

will return your HTML as DOM element already wrapped in jQuery. Otherwise (if you have scripts, events etc) you'll need to use $.parseHTML (as mentioned by @emergence) and pass extra arguments.

Here's official doc for .parseHTML: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/